# Confusion with understanding output impedance on datasheet

Tags: dac, balun

I'm a little confused with a DAC datasheet and its output impedance spec. It says in the table that is has an output internal impedance of 100 ohms but then I look at the circuit application and it shows an output internal resistance of 50 ohms (circled in red). What am I missing?

[image]

DAC datasheet application information

[image]
DAC datasheet electrical characteristics

Comment: 50 + 50 = 100.Trace the circuit from VCCAS round the loop and back. You'll see two 50 ohm resistors in series between one output terminal and the other.

Comment: Got it. I didn't see that if you traced the node around that the two resistors are actually in series. So since its configured this way we have a 100 ohm source.

Comment: Why is the 50 Ohm termination needed on the single ended side?

Answer (score 1):

In differential mode (going from output + to output -), those two resistors are in series. Hence, the output resistance appears 100 Ohm.

Comment: Okay let me try to explain and you tell me if i'm understanding correct...So since its in differential mode with a balun the two resistors inside the DAC appear to be in series because the inductor on the differential side would look like a short so this would complete the circuit for them to look like in series?

Comment: Each source is 50 Ohms but the output is differential, not single-ended so the sum of both sources = 100 ohms

Comment: So the purpose of the Balun here is to convert differential to single-ended but since our source impedance is 100 ohm and our load impedance is 50 0hm we have to use a 2:1 balun? Could we use a 1:1?

Comment: Why is the 50 Ohm termination needed on the single ended side?

Comment: To ensure a good match. The output bandwidth of this DAC seems to be 6 GHz - at these frequencies reflections can become a big issue.

Comment: I wouldn't put a separate 50 ohm termination to ground if I was driving let's say an amplifier because it already has an internal 50 ohm termination?

Comment: Now you're asking if the amplifier has the 50 ohm termination built in. The amplifier's data will tell you that. If it does, it replaces the external termination.

Comment: Okay gotcha, and finally what does it mean "using a 1/Sqrt(2) balun" ? All the baluns I see are represented as 1:1 1:2 or 1:4 etc.

Comment: That's easy; a 1:2 impedance ratio (50:100) corresponds to a 1:sqrt(2) voltage ratio (because Power = V^2/R on both sides).

Comment: I guess I'm not seeing the math of a 1:2 impedance ratio is equal to a 1:sqrt(2) voltage ratio.....sorry

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

\$Z_{diff}=V_{diff} / I_L = (V-(-V)) / I_L = 2\cdot V / I_L = 2\cdot Z_o=100\Omega\$.

Note that I<sub>L</sub> goes from positive side (OUT) to negative side (OUTN).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see this is to ask yourself, "What does a current sink/source and a resistor make?" The answer is that it creates a voltage source with a source impedance.

Look at your diagram. (I'm just going to make up a few numbers to help show the point.) If you sink \$20\:\text{mA}\$ on the left (OUT) side. Then the voltage drop across the \$50\:\Omega\$ resistor would be \$1\:\text{V}\$. So the output would be \$V_{OUT}=V_{CCA5}-1\:\text{V}\$. Now at the same time consider sinking \$50\:\text{mA}\$ on the right (OUTN) side. Then the voltage drop across that other \$50\:\Omega\$ resistor would be \$2.5\:\text{V}\$. So the output would be \$V_{OUTN}=V_{CCA5}-2.5\:\text{V}\$. So these two individual lines, OUT and OUTN, would represent voltage sources. But they also each have a \$50\:\Omega\$ Thevenin output resistance (the current sink itself is taken to be \$\infty\$), too. So you have these two voltages sources, each with \$50\:\Omega\$ Thevenin output resistance, so the resulting total impedance looking at both of them is the sum of the two, or \$100\:\Omega\$. (The voltage differential between them, of course, would be \$1.5\:\text{V}\$.)

Perhaps that perspective helps?